# How to attach a onclick callback to a div but not on a link inside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hyperlink, click

Html

```
<div class='item_container'>

[...bunch of links and pictures...]
<a class='item_owner'>John Doe</a>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
/**
    Bind the onclick only if you hover on the item since we got a lot
    of items and several events and plugins to setup on them.
*/
$('.item_container').live('mouseenter', function(e){
  $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.data('isSetup')) {
    $this.click(function(e){
      // do magic
      return false;
    });
     [... a lot of other stuff]
    $this.data({'isSetup': true});
  }
});
```

Of course when I click anywhere in the div, it performs 'do magic'. Thanks to `return false`, if I click on any link in the div, it still performs 'do magic' and doesn't change the  page, which is the expected behavior.

But there is one link that is suppose to actually change the page, the owner link. Trouble is, with my current set up, I prevent it from working.

Comment: does it do the same if you use `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: check the type of element clicked... this.tagName . If is a link the not return false...

Comment: @2GDev: make that an answer. If it works, you'll get the rep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the event from the links to the parent `.item_container`.

Add this block to the code:

```
$('.item_container a.item_owner').live('click', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Performance wise $('div.item_container a.item_owner') would be better selector

Comment: This would work great if I didn't have other links in the div that are not supposed to stop the propagation. Only the owner link must trigger a page change. The others should not and clicking on them should perform 'do magic' just like the rest of the area.

Comment: Works thanks. I improved it a little bit and turned it into $('a.item_owner', $this). How does this callback stop the probagation of the other callback ? I don't get it: they are separate function!

Comment: It just stops the triggering of the click event and that handles the cancellation of callbacks